# zend project not working on wamp

Tags: .htaccess, zend-framework, wamp

I have copied a zend project deployed on my server to www directory. While running it from wamp server I came across a problem.My url doest not work correctly.Index page loads fine but when I click on any links page not founds error hits.Is there something I am missing in coping data?
Sorry for my english.I am new in zend development

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like that you have not created a virtual host for your project.There is nothing wrong with htaccess

```
  D:\wamp\bin\apache\Apache2.2.11\conf\extra\httpd-vhosts.conf

<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@your-project
    DocumentRoot "D:/wamp/www/your-project/public"
    ServerName ogtt
    ServerAlias www.your-project
    ErrorLog "logs/your-project-error.log"
    CustomLog "logs/your-project-access.log" common
    <directory "D:/wamp/www/your-project/public">
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride all
        Order Deny,Allow
        Allow from 127.0.0.1
    </directory>
</VirtualHost>

then define host name in C:\WINDOWS\system32\drivers\etc\hosts
```

And don't forget to restart your server
Cheers

Comment: Dont forget to upvote for answer if issued is solved